# Javascript redirect: script in symfony route not working

Tags: javascript, symfony, routes, twig

The page I from where I redirect:

```
<a class="uk-overlay" href="{{ path("shot.view",{"id" : id})  }}">
    <img class="uk-border-rounded" src="{{ largeSquare(shot) }}">
    <div class="uk-overlay-area uk-border-rounded">
        <div class="uk-align-right uk-margin-small-top">

            {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}

                {% if app.user.isOwnStar( id ) %}
                    <button class="uk-icon-button uk-icon-star uk-margin-small-right" style="background: #00a8e6;"></button>
                {% else %}
                    <button class="uk-icon-button uk-icon-star uk-margin-small-right" onclick="window.location='{{ path("shot.giveStar",{"id" : id})  }}'"></button>
                {% endif %}

                {% if app.user.isOwnFavorite( id ) %}
                    <button class="uk-icon-button uk-icon-heart uk-margin-small-right" style="background: #d32c46;"></button>
                {% else %}
                    <button class="uk-icon-button uk-icon-heart uk-margin-small-right" onclick="window.location='{{ path("favorite.add",{"id" : id}) }}'"></button>
                {% endif %}

            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

This is a image with an anchor and an overlay which containts some links. Because it is impossible to do nested anchors, i setup this links a buttons with javascript redirect.

The main problem is, that the called symfony route's (from the buttons) script is not executed:

```
public function giveStarAction(Application $app, Request $request, $id)
{
    $msg = $this->shotManager->giveStar($app['user']->getId(),$id);
    $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('info', $msg );
    exit;
    return $app->redirect( $app->path('shot.view', array('id' => $id) ) );
}
```

e.g Route for `path("shot.giveStar",{"id" : id})`

The first three lines were ignored, only the redirect command is executed ...

What do I have to change, that the code is executed before redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its

```
window.location.href = '' 
// or
window.location.replace("")
```

Comment: While your code might (or not) work it would be great if you add a brief explanation about the problem and how does your code solve it. As is it does not provide a full answer according to [answer]

Comment: the code works for sure. if i replace the `<button>` tags with `<a>` and change the overlay from `<a>` to `<div>`, everything works.

Comment: i did it with: `javascript:document.window.location.href` - same problem

Comment: It's not document.window, it's window.document:  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp

you might also try

onclick="function() { window.location.href='xyz'; }